# C# Final testing before beta release. Exception breakpoints... any useful ones we should test for?

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, testing, beta-testing

In the final stages of development and testing before an initial beta release. As part of final stage testing I would like to debug using breakpoints on exceptions and would like to know if any other programmers can recommend some exceptions to enable, and why?

Here are just a few that would be suitable for this exercise...

*System.ArgumentNullException

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

System.NotEnoughCommentsInMethodException

System.NullReferenceException*

App is C#, Winforms, Firebird DB, NHibernate, .NET 4.0

Looking forward to some input!

Comment: "final stage testing" could be better known as "regression testing" and doesn't involve a developer sitting there with a debugger. Either your app falls over or it doesn't. What do you hope to achieve with this testing you propose?

Comment: Well we have great test coverage with our unit and integration tests already. The testing I propose is to run the app in the dev environment catching anything we may have missed. We acknowledge we haven't catered for every user scenario and this testing will hopefully give us more confidence before the beta release. The app is already quite stable but just want to put another measure into place before we release into the wild...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### All of them

If your application is throwing any exceptions whatsoever, you want to be aware of it.

Sometimes, there will be exceptions which are expected; if you come across them you should uncheck them to reduce noise.
However, you should also try to eliminate those (where possible); exceptions should be reserved for exceptional situations.

Comment: Good point and I was thinking this might be an option. What's the easiest way to enable ALL the exceptions in VS2010? It's an awful lot to tick individually!

Comment: Just check the root checkbox in the tree.